# CMS in .NET that can serve content to external websites

Tags: .net, cms

I'm looking for a CMS written in .NET, preferably open source that provides an administrative UI, but has the capability to serve content to other websites via API rather than display content in it's own user facing front end.

A purely cloud based example is https://www.contentful.com/, however I'd like the ability to pull content from a local server rather than a cloud CDN.

Does such a system exist?

Comment: Will RSS feeds serve as a way to deliver content to other web sites?

Comment: No we'll need the cms to be more fully featured than that, be able to serve video, data structures etc.